# aws s3 using boto or aws cli - how to get the recent 5 folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-cli

I have a s3 bucket with nested folder path

```
s3://mainbucket/fold1/fold2/fold3/
```

now folder inside this path there are lot of folders

I want to get the recent 5 folders paths inside the above path

after that i want to get the list of files in each of the recent 5 folders

How can i do this

Comment: You have to get all folders, and the filter them yourself.

Comment: Folders in Amazon S3 don't behave like folders on normal computer. Can you tell us more about what you are seeking and _WHY_ (as opposed to _HOW_)? We might be able to suggest an appropriate approach. For example, are you simply wanting to get a list of all files since a particular date?

Comment: What do you mean by "recent 5 folder paths"? How would you determine 'recency'?

Comment: Amazon S3 "folders" do not have attributes like some Content Managemnet systems do -- such as date. If this is a business requirement for you, you will need to track this type of information such as creating an item in DynamoDB.